# Intl.DateTimeFormat format different in Chrome vs Safari for French format

Tags: javascript, time, formatting, internationalization

The following code snippet gives a different result in Chrome vs Safari

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
  'fr-CA',
  { hour12: false, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' }
).format(1568234174749)
```

- On Safari the result is `16:36` which is incorrect
- On Chrome the result is `16 h 36` which is correct

How do I get the desired result?

My app is a react-native application.

- On Android, react-native uses Chrome for this so the results are correct
- On iOS, react-native uses Safari for this so the results are incorrect

Comment: Replicated on Safari v16. Output is `HH:MM` not `HH h MM` as it is in Chrome v106 and Firefox v106